# remover arquivos com python

Tags: python, biblioteca

Eu fiz esse código para verificar dentro da minha pasta documentos se um determinado arquivo existe e, se existe, excluí-lo. Porém, mesmo o arquivo existindo, ele não o exclui, sempre entra na condição de que o arquivo não existe:

```
import os

class Removedor:
    def Remover():
        arq = str(input('Qual arquivo deseja remover? '))
        for file in os.listdir('/home/paulo/Documentos'):
            if os.path.exists(arq):
                os.remove(arq)
            else:
                print('O arquivo não existe!')

Removedor.Remover()
```

Comment: É erro de digitação, faltou o caminho da pasta no `os.path.exists` e no `os.remove`, não é necessário o listdir(), fora que o código possui problema de *race condition*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas considerações:

1. Não use mais a biblioteca `os` para manipular arquivos. Ela é mais antiga e deve ser substituída pela `pathlib`, que tem uma API bem mais consistente;
2. Não recomendo que faça a leitura do `input` e a exclusão do arquivo na mesma função, pois isso faz com que sua função fica impura e pode te atrapalhar em desenvolvimentos futuros;
3. Converter a saída da função `input` para `str` é redundância, pois o retorno de `input` **sempre** é uma string;
4. Não faça a validação se o arquivo existe antes de excluí-lo, pois faz com que a sua operação não seja atômica e gera uma condição de corrida bastante difícil de identificar na prática.

Dito isso, uma boa solução para o seu problema poderia se resumir a:

```py
import pathlib


file = input('Qual arquivo deseja excluir? ')
pathlib.Path(f'/home/paulo/Documentos/{file}').unlink(missing_ok=True)
```

Aqui fazemos:

1. Uso da biblioteca `pathlib` ao invés da `os`;
2. Uso da classe `Path` para manipular o arquivo desejado;
3. Método `unlink` para excluir o arquivo, com o parâmetro `missing_ok=True` para informar que não deve levantar uma exceção caso o arquivo não exista.

#### Problema no seu código

```py
import os

class Removedor:
    def Remover():
        arq = str(input('Qual arquivo deseja remover? '))  #  <-------
        for file in os.listdir('/home/paulo/Documentos'):
            if os.path.exists(arq):  #  <-------
                os.remove(arq)
            else:
                print('O arquivo não existe!')

Removedor.Remover()
```

Você está validando a existência do arquivo sem informar em qual diretório ele se encontra, `os.path.exists(arq)`, ou seja, sempre valida se o arquivo que o usuário informar existe na mesma pasta que o seu arquivo Python. Como não existe, sempre entra no `else`. Você precisaria corrigir para informar em qual diretório deseja validar a existência do arquivo, bem como remover o laço `for` do `os.listdir`, pois é desnecessário listar todos os arquivos do diretório para verificar se o arquivo existe.

Comment: Funcionou como eu queria, obrigado!